# Modifying Docker Registry based on environment

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My local development environment is behind a corporate proxy, with our own Docker registry, etc. However, we deploy on public infrastructure, meaning we can't access the corporate registries, and so have to pull from a public one (eg DockerHub).

Is there any way (eg via environment variables) for me to configure Docker to pull from a private registry when developing locally, and from a public registry when it goes through our CI/CD pipeline?

For example, let's say we're deploying a Node.JS application - locally, I would want the `FROM node:16` line to get interpreted as `FROM corporate.proxy/node:16`.

There are a couple methods that would probably work - having two separate Dockerfiles, eg `Dockerfile.dev` and `Dockerfile.prod`, or wrapping it in some sort of script that will take care of making the change. I'm looking for a way to do it via Docker's configuration, if it's possible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ARG instruction to change the FROM line in Dockerfile.

```
ARG IMG
FROM ${IMG}
```

Then you can build image like this:

```
docker build --build-arg IMG=node:16 .
```

or

```
docker build --build-arg IMG=corporate.proxy/node:16 .
```

From Dockerfile reference document:

> ARG is the only instruction that may precede FROM in the Dockerfile

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact